# Google Calendar : Cannot find com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory.fromInputStream

Tags: java, json, maven, google-api, google-api-java-client

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am trying to integrate Calendar functionality. Unfortunately I am stuck at the authentication phase itself because of json error. I am trying to use Googles sample code which was outdated, so I made a few modifications. Kindly have a look. 
Error log :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory.fromInputStream(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets.load(GoogleClientSecrets.java:167)
    com.journaldev.spring.utility.OAuth.authorize(OAuth.java:73)
```

Oauth class, where I implement calendar functionality.

```
public class OAuth {

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "appname";

    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR =
            new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "" +
                    "/Store/calendar_sample");

    private static FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;

    private static HttpTransport httpTransport;

    private static final com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    private static com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar client;

    static final java.util.List<Calendar> addedCalendarsUsingBatch = Lists.newArrayList();

    public void authorizeAndTest(){

        try {
            httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
            Credential credential = authorize();

            client = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(httpTransport,JSON_FACTORY,credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

            showCalenders();
            addCalendarsUsingBatch();
            Calendar calendar = addCalendar();
            updateCalendar(calendar);
            addEvent(calendar);
            showEvents(calendar);
            deleteCalendarInBatch();
            deleteCalendar(calendar);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Credential authorize() throws Exception{


        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("/home/akshay/c0cc3b4b7502.json"));


        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,inputStream);
```

// Happening at this line.

```
   if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
            || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
        System.out.println(
                "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=calendar "
                        + "into calendar-cmdline-sample/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
        return null;
    }

    AuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport,JSON_FACTORY,clientSecrets,
            Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR)).setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory).build();

    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow,new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user@gmail.com");
}
```

Pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3-alpha</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
        <version>v3-rev35-1.13.2-beta</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>1.47.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-auth-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3-alpha</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1-beta</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Error log as requested by David :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:76)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:37)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets.getDetails(GoogleClientSecrets.java:82)
    at com.journaldev.spring.utility.OAuth.authorize(OAuth.java:75)
    at com.journaldev.spring.utility.OAuth.authorizeAndTest(OAuth.java:53)
    at com.journaldev.spring.controller.PersonController.listCanvas(PersonController.java:586)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1179)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
```

Comment: I am still stuck at the problem, can really use some help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use the constructor of `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder` that takes two parameters `String clientId` and `String clientSecret` instead of your json, that might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you need to take into account :

1. The dependency `com.google.gdata.core` is not required for the Calendar API. Unless you need it for another Google API you can remove it
2. You have two implementations of the `google-http-client` : `google-http-client-jackson` and `google-http-client-jackson2`. You need to remove one of those.
3. You're using unnecessary and too old dependencies such as `google-api-client-auth-oauth2:1.2.3-alpha` and `google-api-client:1.4.1-beta`
4. The versions of the `google-api-services-calendar` and `google-http-client-jackson2` do not match. For `google-http-client-jackson2:1.19.0` you need to use `google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev121-1.19.0`. Notice that the version of the HTTP client is the same as the suffix of the calendar client's version ?
5. The `google-oauth-client-java6` dependency must be replaced by `google-oauth-client-jetty` if you want to use the `LocalServerReceiver` class.

In the end, here's my working set of dependencies and slightly updated `OAuth` class :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
        <version>v3-rev121-1.19.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Note that you will need to change the path to the json file :

```
public class OAuth {

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "APPNAME";

    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR =
            new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "" +
                    "/Store/calendar_sample");

    private static FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;

    private static HttpTransport httpTransport;

    private static final com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

    private static com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar client;


    public void authorizeAndTest() {

        try {
            httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
            Credential credential = authorize();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {


        FileReader credentialsReader = new FileReader(new File("client_secret_47576556653-go0fkf4c56dohm6m16s2400qed5ps410.apps.googleusercontent.com.json"));

// It gives me an error for line below.
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, credentialsReader);
        if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
                || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=calendar "
                            + "into calendar-cmdline-sample/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
            return null;
        }

        AuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
                Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR)).setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory).build();

        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user@gmail.com");
    }
```

Comment: This helped me solve this problem, but I think this FileReader is causing problem. Can you please check this error : http://s8.postimg.org/iftvazk5h/Screenshot_from_2015_03_23_14_56_12.png

Comment: I have added the error log, it is happening at the if loop. Can you please check.

Comment: I created a Client Id, which has the client id and secret, do you know where I can paste it instead of using the JSON file, so that I can get this code running. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, Stackoverflow says I can offer my bounty in 17 Hours, I will do it tomorrow then..Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just Comment below dependency from your Pom.xml and try:

```
    <!--dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-auth-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3-alpha</version>
    </dependency-->
```

not this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1-beta</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this could help you.

Comment: That didn't help, as per you said, I commented out the google-api-client-auth-oauth2. Same error.

Comment: could your share me import details of OAuth class.

Comment: Here you go : http://pastebin.com/xN3SH5Nc  and if you want pom.xml : http://pastebin.com/XfWRJ33c

Comment: just check with passing inputStream instead of Reader.

Comment: That was for old GoogleClientSecrets, when I do it, I get the following problem, check the screenshot : http://s3.postimg.org/y0flppjab/Screenshot_from_2015_03_23_14_29_34.png

Comment: could you check  GoogleClientSecrets is pointing to which jar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73583/discussion-between-gaurav-mishra-and-we-are-borg).